# Handling multiple compilations of wxWidgets

Tags: c++, mingw, wxwidgets, ubuntu-16.04

I am planning to develop a small scale gui application using wxWidgets on Ubuntu 16.10. I have downloaded the source package of version 3.1.0 and I am able to build the package succesfully for the native platform and for Windows with MinGW.

However, the problem is that I could not figure out what prefixes I should pass to the `../configure --prefix=` command.

If I do not pass anything for prefixes and then install both of them using `make install`, 2nd one overrides the 1st one. Although wx-config shows the other configuration as "Also found in /usr/local...", I am not able to select it using `--toolkit=gtk2` option, wx-config says that there is no such build.

So basically, what should be the prefixes for each build according to linux naming rules and wxWidgets conventions in general?

Note: builds are: `gtk2-unicode-static-3.1` and `x86_64-w64-mingw32-msw-unicode-static-3.1`

Comment: Sure you need the `--prefix=` option?

Comment: As I said, I couldn't make wx-config select one or the other without prefix. Is there any other *proper* method of having multiple builds? If yes, I'd appreciate that...

Comment: The `--prefix` option is intended you're going to install your library anywhere else than in the `/usr/lib` or `/usr/lib64` directories (along separate directories for `/usr/include` as well). Did you bother to read the autoconf documentation?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I forgot to look at that particular documentation. But got my answer, though. Thanks anyway...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In principle, `wx-config` is definitely supposed to be able to select between multiple builds of the same library (this is about 90% of its entire logic and purpose in life), but I'm afraid there might be a problem with `wx-config` logic for the build selection and `--host` option, which would be needed to select the right build in your case.

I'm not sure myself because I actually never use `wx-config` to select between multiple builds and instead simply never install them at all and use the script from the build directory. I.e. what I'm certain does work is:

```shell
$ mkdir -p ~/build/wx/gtk
$ cd $_
$ ~/src/wx/configure # of course, you can add other options, if needed
$ make -s
$ mkdir ../msw
$ cd $_
$ ~/src/wx/configure --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --with-msw
$ make -s
$ cd ~/src/my/program
$ make WX_CONFIG=~/build/wx/gtk/wx-config # or the MSW one
```

Using a wxWidgets build without installing it like this does waste some disk space (you can do `rm *.o` to reclaim most of it, of course -- just don't do `make clean` which would erase the libraries too), but otherwise it has only advantages:

1. You don't need any special rights which are typically required to write to `/usr/local` or wherever.
2. You can easily have as many builds as you need and choosing between them is explicit by just selecting the right `wx-config`.
3. If anything goes wrong, you can just `rm -rf ~/build/wx/whatever` at any moment and start anew.